# Entity Framework 4, can I have 2 tables from different db servers in the same model?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

With Entity Framework 4, can I have 2 tables from different db servers in the same model?
I have table X from SQL Server A and Table Y from Server B.
Is it possible to have different connection string per table under one model or do I need to have different dbml files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't. Whole EDMX file have single connection string. Moreover EF don't allow fully qualified names of tables. Defining table `TableA` a from linked server `MyServer.MyDatabase.dbo` will probably in SQL query result in something like [MyServer.MyDatabase.dbo].[TableA] and it will throw exception.

If you want support tables from two servers in a single model, try to link your second server to the first server and create a view for each table from the second server in your current database on the first server.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you might be able to fully qualify the table name in the DBML if they are linked servers. I don't have anything to test on, I know you can do it in Linq2Sql on Different databases on the same server.